# Two filter in one line? is possible? using Javascript filter

Tags: php

I have two filter function but is possible to be in one line?
Check my code:

this is work fine but is possible to be on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `filter()` returns an array, and `filter()` can be called on an array.  Which the code shown already demonstrates.  So you can certainly remove the intermediate variable and just call `filter()` directly on the result of the previous `filter()` operation:

```
let newValue = objectVersion.filter(Boolean).filter((al) => al.status || al.data);
```

You can also combine the logic into a single call to `filter()`.  What is `Boolean` in this case?  Is it just looking for any values which are ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)?  If so then you can do something like this:

```
let newValue = objectVersion.filter((al) => al && (al.status || al.data));
```

Or if it's meant here to represent a function that you otherwise pass to `filter()` then you can invoke it just the same:

```
let newValue = objectVersion.filter((al) => yourFunction(al) && (al.status || al.data));
```

Basically, yes... You can combine any boolean expressions into one larger expression or alternatively you can chain as many calls to `filter()` (or any other array method which returns an array) as you like.

Answer (score 2):

`Boolean` is just filtering for truthy values, so you can write the filter with just `&&`:

```js
let newValue = objectVersion.filter((al) => al && (al.status || al.data));
```